# Android compile single .java file to .class

Tags: java, android, jar, android-library

I have same jar lib for android where I need change class. I opened .jar find and decompile class, do same changes. I need add updated file to jar. As I understand I need compile .java to .class, and then repack jar.

I try convert to classes with `javac.exe MyClass.java` and I get a lot of errors like

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
.java:8: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Context;
.java:9: error: package android.graphics does not exist
import android.graphics.Color;
```

in total 149 errors

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These error messages are the java compiler telling you that there's some android dependencies that he can't figure out how or where to find.

I don't think it's possible to achieve this, because it seems your class relies on Android framework resources.

Take a look at: 
[compile android app with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943418/compile-android-app-with-javac)

Did you consider inheritance ? I mean, the desired different behaviour for android maybe can be achieved by inheriting the class then overriding the specific method with new behaviour, I'm just guessing, since I don't have enough info about your problem.